# AS3 .Slice accepting variables?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm working on a project which accepts input text from the user, processes the input and does various calulations and then outputs text in the same format, but with different figures.

The format of the input text may change over time and since I need to carve out roughly 200 fields from the Input using variable.Slice(?, ?);, maintainance of this project in the future is a huge concern.

The question is, can the .slice(?,?) have variable names in place of the ?, or does it always need to be numbers?

I've searched extensively before resorting to asking here. I dont beleive code is required for this question but if someone needs an example just let me know.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why didnt you just try it ;)
**Yes** Ofcourse you can use var's. 
 slice() expects `int` as parameters. It doesnt matter if that `int` is hardcoded or a variable!